# Plugging values into functions

Tags: functions

I am very new to *Mathematica*, and need to know how to plug values into existing functions. For example, Math World [supplies the following code](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TruthTable.html) for building a truth table of `n` levels of operator `op`:

```
TruthTable[op_, n_] := 
Module[{l = 
 Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ Table[{True, False}, {n}]], 
  n - 1], a = Array[A, n]}, 
DisplayForm[
GridBox[Prepend[Append[#, op @@ #] & /@ l, Append[a, op @@ a]], 
 RowLines -> True, ColumnLines -> True]]]
```

How do I set the operator and the value of `n`?

Comment: You've seen `BooleanTable[]` already?

Comment: You say "Mathematica supplies the following code for building a truth table of n levels of operator op". It it not known to my copy of Mathematica. I found it on Math World, which is not same as "supplied by Mathematica".

Comment: @J.M. I have seen BooleanTable[] and the related functions and did not have problems with those--I'm only unsure about the notation used above.

Comment: @m_goldberg: I meant "supplied by Wolfram".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some results of my trying out this function on my copy of *Mathematica*:

[image: notebook selection]

Comment: I see you've used an '@' in your definition of the op--is this a standard way of avoiding nested parentheses? Also, can you tell me about the use of the '&' at the end of the definition?

Comment: @Quiet, `@` is a *prefix* method of applying a function; that is, `f @ x` and `f[x]` are the same thing. There's a postfix version, `x // f`. `&`, on the other hand, is shorthand for the `Function[]` construct, which allows you to use *pure functions*. Look at the docs for `Function[]` for more detail on this.

Comment: @J.M: Thanks a lot, that's very helpful.=)